# ActiveDirectory error 0x8000500c when traversing properties

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I got the following snippet (`SomeName`/`SomeDomain` contains real values in my code)

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=SomeName,OU=All Groups,dc=SomeDomain,dc=com");
foreach (object property in entry.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property);
}
```

It prints OK for the first 21 properties, but then fail with:

```
COMException {"Unknown error (0x8000500c)"}
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.PropertyEnumerator.get_Entry()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.PropertyEnumerator.get_Current()
   at ActiveDirectory.Tests.IntegrationTests.ObjectFactoryTests.TestMethod1() in MyTests.cs:line 22
```

Why? How can I prevent it?

**Update**

It's a custom attribute that fails.

I've tried to use `entry.RefreshCache()` and `entry.RefreshCache(new[]{"theAttributeName"})` before enumerating the properties (which didn't help).

**Update2**

`entry.InvokeGet("theAttributeName")` works (and without `RefreshCache`).

Can someone explain why?

**Update3**

It works if I supply the FQDN to the item: `LDAP://srv00014.ssab.com/CN=SomeName,xxxx`

**Bounty**

I'm looking for an answer which addresses the following:

- Why `entry.Properties["customAttributeName"]` fails with the mentioned exception
- Why `entry.InvokeGet("customAttributeName")` works
- The cause of the exception
- How to get both working

Comment: My first guess at _why_ would be permissions. What context are you running under?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Just tried with an account that should have enough privileges. No difference :(

Comment: Can you try specifying 'God' credentials explicitly via the constructor? Just as a sanity check.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: We got a custom attribute which is the one that I can't access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If one wants to access a custom attribute from a machine that is not
>   part of the domain where the custom attribute resides (the credentials
>   of the logged in user don't matter) one needs to pass the fully
>   qualified name of the object is trying to access otherwise the schema
>   cache on the client machine is not properly refreshed, nevermind all
>   the schema.refresh() calls you make

Found [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/checking-accessing-custom-attribute-fails-0x8000500c-t2114136.html).  This sounds like your problem, given the updates made to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same failure. I´m read and saw a lot of questions about the error 0x8000500c by listing attribute from a DirectoryEntry.
I could see, with the Process Monitor (Sysinternals), that my process has read a schema file. This schema file is saved under
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SchCache\xyz.sch.

Remove this file and the program works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the Err.exe tool here

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=985

It spits out:
 for hex 0x8000500c / decimal -2147463156 :
  E_ADS_CANT_CONVERT_DATATYPE                                   adserr.h
 The directory datatype cannot be converted to/from a native
 DS datatype
 1 matches found for "0x8000500c"

Googled "The directory datatype cannot be converted to/from a native" and found this KB:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907462

Comment: @jgauffin can you let us know what OS version & SP level? also what is this 22nd property? can you see it using ADSIEDIT.MSC? does that cause an exception/crash when you view this 22nd property? what about the MMC AD Snap-in what does that do when you view this property?

Comment: woops custom attribute forget the MMC bit, look this might be a red herring but its not a Not Set property is it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990505/net-code-to-set-an-active-directory-attribute-to-not-set

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the issue and mine was with a web application. 
I had this bit of code which pulls the user out of windows authentication in IIS and pulls their info from AD.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var name = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, this.user.Identity.Name);
    if (principal != null)
    {
        this.fullName = principal.GivenName + " " + principal.Surname;
    }
    else
    {
        this.fullName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This worked fine in my tests, but when I published the website it would come up with this error on FindByIdentity call.

**I fixed the issue by using correct user for the app-pool of the website. As soon as I fixed that, this started working.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a custom attribute of a weird data type. I had a utility program that would extract the value, but some more structured code in a service that would not.

The utility was working directly with a SearchResult object, while the service was using a DirectoryEntry.

It distilled out to this.

```
SearchResult result;

result.Properties[customProp];     // might work for you
result.Properties[customProp][0];  // works for me. see below

using (DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
{
    entry.Properties[customProp]; // fails
    entry.InvokeGet(customProp);  // fails as well for the weird data
}
```

My gut feel is that the SearchResult is a little less of an enforcer and returns back whatever it has.

When this is converted to a DirectoryEntry, this code munges the weird data type so that even InvokeGet fails.

My actual extraction code with the extra [0] looks like:

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])((result.Properties[customProp][0]));
String customValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

I picked up the second line from another posting on the site.