# LDAP error (0x8000500c) when accessing SOME attributes through C# code with administrator credentials

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, directoryservices

I am trying to read an attribute from an LDAP (not AD) entry using C# and the .NET library 'System.DirectoryServices'.

My LDAP entry is the following:

```
dn: uid=foo,ou=People,dc=companyname,dc=local
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
gidNumber: 0
givenName: Foo
sn: Bar
displayName: Foo Bar
uid: foo
homeDirectory: /
cn: foo bar
uidNumber: 9846
userPassword: {SHA}Ys23Ag/5IOWqZCw9QGaVDdHwH00=
mail: foo@dodo.net
```

The Linux LDAP server I am using is "389", also known as "Fedora Directory Server". My C# code looks like this:

```
string value = null;
DirectoryEntry ouEntry = null;
string path = "LDAP://192.168.150.192/ou=People, dc=companyname, dc=local";
string adminUserName = "cn=Directory Manager";
string adminPassword = "supersecureadminpassword";
ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, adminUserName, adminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.None);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ouEntry, "uid=foo");
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
var props = userEntry.Properties.PropertyNames;
if(userEntry.Properties.Contains("givenName"))
    value = userEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
```

The code works perfectly fine. However, if I replace "givenName" by "displayName" the code fails on the line `if(userEntry.Properties.Contains("displayName"))` with a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x8000500c)`.
And that happens, even though the attribute "displayName" shows up when inspecting the property list `props`.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737599/activedirectory-error-0x8000500c-when-traversing-properties), because it seems to be a similar problem. However, I don't know how to fix the problem, because all I have is a static IP address and not a fully qualified name for my LDAP server.

Has anybody any idea what the problem in my code is and if it is related to the mentioned post? How would I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Update 1:**
I've also tried to replace the IP address by the LDAP server's Linux host name (the output of the shell command `hostname`), but that didn't work either. Also, "displayName" is not a custom attribute, as far as I know. Therefore, my problem probably does not match the problem in the linked post.
I am really desperate and don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. adminUserName is a login name, e.g. "jsmith" not "cn=..."
2. if your box is in the same domain then usually you don't need to specify user/password
3. make sure that uid (uid=foo) is the right property
4. try to use PropertiesToLoad

   ```
   DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ouEntry, ...);
   searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
   ```

Although you said it works for "givenName", you might try to test a third party tool to check if there is no problem with your connection. E.g. you might try [LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm), try to provide same connection data and perform a search for your filter string and see if it returns all required data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Referring to your suggestions:

1.) Are you sure? Shouldn't it be a LDAP distinguished name? How else would you distinguish between user of different OUs?

Anyway, even if I replace `"cn=Directory Manager"` by `"Directory Manager"`, I still get the same error at the same line.

2.) Ok, but it should work regardless, right?

3.) It is the right property. I am also using [LDAP Admin](http://www.ldapadmin.org) as an LDAP browser and checked all the attributes.

4.) I had tried that before and it doesn't make a difference.

Do you have any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I see you said, it's an LDAP not AD. In this case you're right it might be CN=... however it is strange that it does not change its output when you changed "Directory Manager" without CN= - so it looks like this is the issue. Try to specify "abc" instead of real password - I believe you'll get the same result. Did you try other than AuthenticationType.None?